# Facebook Tag photo with contacts synced in the phone contact list [iOS]

Tags: ios, facebook, tags

I am building a photo editing editing app.
I want that user should be able to tag the photos using the fb contacts synced in the contact list of the phone, which he can share later.
Is that possible using facebook sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Using Facebook Open Graph actions you can tag friends. Look here: [developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#taggingpeople](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#taggingpeople)

Comment: I think you didn't understand the problem statment properly.
Opengraph can be used to tag only those friends who are using the app.

I want to tag friends from the contact list of the phone.